# dos command findstr search string withing specified bytes

Tags: dos, findstr

Could I use findstr to search a string between specified bytes/positions only..

For example I have a text file and each line has maximum 1000 bytes

I wanted to search lines with a string in between byte number 50 to 100 only?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be relatively easy to solve using regular expressions (regex). But unfortunately, FINDSTR support for regex is extremely limited. It does not have the features needed to solve your problem.

You could use [grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) instead of FINDSTR, but that requires a download.

Assuming you want to find `my string` somewhere between positions 50 and 100 on any line within "file.txt":

```
grep "^.\{49,91\}my string" file.txt
```

Another option is to switch to another scripting language with full support for regex. JScript, VBScript, and PowerShell can all be used to easily solve this problem.

A pure native batch solution requires a non-trivial script, and is much slower. Here is one possible solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%L in (file.txt) do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "ln=!ln:~49,51!"
  if "!ln:my string=!" neq "!ln!" echo !ln!
  endlocal
)
```